# How to access value in another class, returned by a DataTable and bind it to grid view in C# in 3 tier architecture

Tags: c#

Here is my Connection class, in which I am establishing a connection, passing a query to, filling data, and returning a data table:

```
    public DataTable GetGridData(String query)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-NJ5IBFU;Initial Catalog=practiceDb;Integrated Security=True");

        try
        {

            conn.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter a = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);

            DataTable t = new DataTable();
            a.Fill(t);


            if (t.Rows.Count > 0)
            {

            }
            return t;
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
            return null;
        }
```

This is my data access layer, overloaded function:

```
        public void FillGrid()
    {
        String q = "Select * from customer_info";
        DbCon con = new DbCon();

        con.GetGridData(q);
    }
```

Here is a function from my business layer:

```
    public void FillGrid()
    {
        customerDal dl = new customerDal();
        try
        {
            dl.FillGrid();
        }
        catch
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

And here is my partial design class. I want to bind grid view to data table:

```
 private void bunifuThinButton24_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bl.FillGrid(p);
      // Here is the problem I think. I am instantiating a new object.
      // I want to access the dataTable returned by the connection class in this 
      // class
        DataTable t = new DataTable();
        bunifuCustomDataGrid1.DataSource = t; 
    }
```

All of these classes are in separate projects, and I've added references in each project.

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning your `DataTable` from `FillGrid`, which btw. has a strange name, as it does not fill any grid. Change the return type from `void` to `DataTable` and return the result.

```
public DataTable FillGrid()
{
    String q = "Select * from customer_info";
    DbCon con = new DbCon();

    return con.GetGridData(q);
}
```

Same thing in the BL

```
public DataTable FillGrid()
{
    customerDal dl = new customerDal();
    try
    {
        return dl.FillGrid();
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```

Then fill the grid with

```
private void bunifuThinButton24_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bunifuCustomDataGrid1.DataSource = bl.FillGrid(p); 
}
```

Also, you seem to leave the connection open. Use a `using`-statement, which does automatically close the connection and dispose any resources.

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP...;Integrated Security=True")) {
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        ...
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ...
    }        
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've successfully populated the grid view. I've another question, I also have properties layer in my project which i use to set, get the values that i receive from text field and pass them to business layer. Can I use that class too in this particular scenario.

Comment: You can use data binding in winforms and WPF to bind your data automatically to text boxes. You will find tutorials online for that. Otherwise post this as a new question.